# C# object to int for MYSQL datediff

Tags: c#, mysql, object, int

I got help from someone very nice that provided me with this code:
the code works excellent and displays days left however I need it to be an int so I can create an if method to check if their subscribtion is over.

```
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATEDIFF(end_date, NOW()) FROM `as_users` WHERE username = '" + this.username_txt.Text + "'";
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), end_date)'", conn);
        int daysLeft = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show("Days Left: " + cmd.ExecuteScalar());
       if (daysLeft => 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("expired");
        }
    }
```

I get this error
cannot implicitly convert type 'object to 'int

Comment: Updated code in my post.  Changed `=>` to `>=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is the code update.  You needed to convert it properly.  You an an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion, what you need is an [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx%20%22explicit%22%20conversion.) conversion.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATEDIFF(end_date, NOW()) FROM `as_users` WHERE username = '" + this.username_txt.Text + "'";
conn.Open();
int daysLeft = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
MessageBox.Show("Days Left: " + daysLeft );
if (daysLeft >= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("expired");
}
```

Comment: Oh woops! Thanks so much once I'll try to get 15rep by today to upvote you :) thanks for being a polite and awesome coder

Comment: Ha, no problem.  Mark it as the answer if it has fixed your problem.  You also had `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` twice, which was wrong.  You needed to call that once, store the value and then use that value going forward.  Nor did you need the `SelectCommand` variable, it was pointless, so I have updated my code and removed that too...

Answer (score 0):

> public override Object ExecuteScalar()

This is the signature of ExecuteScalar Method. It returns an Object that cannot be casted into an Integer.

I recommend that you change that cast to an Implicit conversion.

```
int daysLeft = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: What about his second call to `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` - Although not in his question, it's a mistake on his part...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Convert.ToInt32() instead. Simply do 
int daysLeft = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: What about his second call to `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` - Although not in his question, it's a mistake on his part...

Comment: It looks like he is executing the same command, if so it will be a better option to just use the 'daysLeft' variable instead. Wouldn't it? Just like how you have in your answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, same with his `SelectCommand` variable, it wasn't needed... Also, you might wanna read up on the syntax highlighting available (simply put it's "highlight code section hold ctrl and press k").  Makes your posts easier to read... :)